# st_join() inconsistent behaviour - should I trust the result? old version sf?

Tags: r, r-sf

I am trying to match some points with long/lat coordinates with the associated regions using a map from [GADM](https://gadm.org/) and st_join(). So the code is very simple:

```
x <- st_read(my_map)
y <- st_as_sf(my_points, coords = c('long', 'lat')
st_crs(y) = 4326
y <- st_join(y,x)
```

where both x and y are sf objects (x with polygons, y with points).

The issue is between my home and office computer, one works and the other one throws an error.

My home computer which runs the code without any issues is running on R4.0.4 and sf_0.9-7 (which I realise is older) on a Windows10x64

My office compute runs on R4.0.5 with sf_1.0-2 on a Windows10x64.
Here's the error code:

```
Error in s2_geography_from_wkb(x, oriented = oriented, check = check) : 
  Evaluation error: Found 4 features with invalid spherical geometry.
[201] Loop 2 is not valid: Edge 2 crosses edge 4
[935] Loop 16 edge 390 crosses loop 64 edge 6
[2667] Loop 20 edge 835 crosses loop 37 edge 24843
[3401] Loop 1 is not valid: Edge 818 crosses edge 820
```

Do you know if I can trust the output of the join by using the older version of the package? I briefly looked at the issues in Github but couldn't find something to alarm me, it might just be that they changed one default to FALSE. But I'm wondering if that is something that I should be wary of.

Comment: The new version (from 1.0) is using [s2](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf7.html) to do the spatial operaitons. To get the same result as pre1.0 you need to `sf::st_use_s2(FALSE)`.

Comment: But for calculations on a sphere, you probably want to be using S2, because I belive it's more accurate. However, it's more fussy about the geometries (winding order of rings, self-intersecting polygons etc), which is what the errors you're getting are now telling you.

Comment: Thanks very much - just saw your comments! I ended up not using the results for this exact reason, and went with another strategy.